# I forgot to file my T4 tax form. Will this affect my mortgage?

Tags: canada, mortgage, form-t4a

I'm in Quebec, Canada. Tomorrow I am submitting an application for mortgage through a mortgage agent.

Because I started working at a new job in December 2014, I was asked for my T4 forms and notices of assessment.

I realized that I forgot to file the T4 for this new job.  I will fix this as soon as possible, but...

Will this affect my mortgage application?

Comment: what do you mean by "file the T4"? You mean you haven't done your tax return for 2014? Or you didn't give the T4 to the mortgage people?